# Sending message to object using selector and NSSelectorFromString

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, selector

The following will pass the `respondsToSelector` test, but `SIGABRT` on the actual call to `[viewController selector]` or `[viewController action:selector]`. The stack trace states 'NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: -[MyViewController selector]: unrecognized selector'.

`[viewController @selector(selector)]` will cause a compile error (error: expected ':' before 'selector').

When the selector is hard coded, all works well.

How do I send a message to an object through a selector?

```
-(void) notifyViewControllers:(NSString*) message
{
    if(!message) return;

    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(message);
    if(!selector) return;

    NSArray* viewControllers = [self.tabBarController viewControllers];
    if(!viewControllers) return;

    for (UIViewController* viewController in viewControllers)
    {
        if(!viewController) continue;

        if ([viewController respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            // [viewController selector];
            [viewController action:selector];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(notifyViewControllers:) withObject: message];
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
[viewController performSelector:selector];
```

Also check other methods NSObject in performSelector 'family' - with them you can easily call selector with delay and/or on background thread.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. Rakesh beat you to it (performSelector) - but yours was precisely correct.

Answer (score 2):

Could be useful to know how to do this where you cannot use performSelector, maybe because the selector string must be used within a protocol method:

In order to allow the selector supporting parameters, it should be specified as follow:

```
NSString *stringForSelector = @"doSomethingAwesome:"; // notice the colon
```

Let's say we're going to handle a tap gesture

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString(stringForSelector)];
```

UIGestureRecognizer class allow to use the recognizer itself in the action callback:

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
```

So to do something awesome on Tap, we could write:

```
- (void)doSomethingAwesome:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
    // gesture handling with UIGestureRecognizer availability
}
```